# How To calculate summary of Jqgrid Column In asp.net

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

Hii Guys!!
              I developed a jqgrid in which i need to calculate summary of 'duration' and 'price' columns on footer of the grid But i dont have idea how to do this as I am first time using the Jqgrid..
Below is My code ....

```
 var categoriesStr = ":All;1:vikas;2:Ankur";
    $(function () {
        $("#UsersGrid").jqGrid({
            url: 'getGriddahico.ashx',
            datatype: 'json',
            height: 250,
            colNames: ['UserID', 'username', 'ordinal', 'authcode', 'extension', 'trunk', 'dialnumber', 'dialdate', 'dialtime', 'duration', 'destination', 'price', 'toc'],
            colModel: [
                    { name: 'UserID', index: 'UserID', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center',hidden:true },
                    { name: 'username', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'ordinal', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'authcode', width: 100, sortable: true },
                    { name: 'extension', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'trunk', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'dialnumber', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'dialdate', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'dialtime', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'duration', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'destination', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'price', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'toc', width: 150, sortable: true, align: 'center' }
                ],
            rowNum: 100,
            rowList: [100, 200, 300],
            pager: '#UsersGridPager',
            sortname: 'username',
            //loadonce: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            ignoreCase:true,
            sortorder: 'asc',
            autowidth: true,
            toppager: true,
            height: '100%'

        });

        $("#UsersGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#UsersGridPager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false });


        jQuery("#UsersGrid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false });
    });
```

Any Help will be Heartily Welcomed ..
Thanx in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would calculate those values in your controller and then pass them in via userdata in your JSon. Ex

```
records = totalRecords,
                userdata = new { price: Value1, toc: Value2 //etc },
                rows = (
```

Inside your jqGrid configuration you would also turn on

```
        footerrow: true,
        userDataOnFooter: true,
```

Then with your above sample code Value1 would be displayed in the footer of the price column and Value2 would be displayed in the footer of the toc column.